# Chess challenge #9: Can you solve it in less than 5 minutes?

Tags: endgame, checkmate, problems

Today I remembered this position that I saw a few months ago in [a tweet by Sergey Karjakin](https://twitter.com/SergeyKaryakin/status/608180812949950464):

```
[fen "2k5/8/8/BQ6/4K3/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

It seemed very easy to me because there are just 4 pieces left but it was much more difficult than I expected. Sergey was asked to solve it in less than five minutes as part of a bet (which he won).  White to play and mate in 3. **Can you also solve it in less than 5 minutes? :)**

Comment: I failed to solve it in 5 minutes.

Comment: @TonyEnnis Don't give up! It happened the same to me the first time that I saw this puzzle

Comment: I already cheated. I was on the right track, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it barely under the mark.  Not sure if it helped or hurt that I knew the mate-in-2 with a similar position (move the Ke4 to f5).

> 1 Qb2!! Kd7 2 Qe5! Kc8/Kc6 3 Qc7/Qd5#!

*Spoiler for mate in 2* (Kf5 Qb5 Ba5 / Kc8):

> 1 Qb3! Kd7 2 Qe6#!

Comment: On your mate in 2, 2... Kxe6

Comment: 2... Kxe6 3 KxK.  Note wK on f5.

Answer (score 0):

Favourite task of V. Lenin ))
1. Qb2 2.Qe5